# Android physical keyboard Hungarian QWERTY layout missing

Tags: android, keyboard, qwerty

I got a Logitech K380 physical keyboard and I want to use the Hungarian QWERTY style keyboard layout on my Samsung Android tablet.
The issue is that, while for the Samsung Keyboard under Settings > Languages and types, I can select Hungarian then select Qwerty, when I go to Physical keyboard settings > Samsung Keyboard - Hungarian, the only option there is 'Hungarian, Qwertz style', there is no Qwerty style. That's strange because for some other languages, e.g. Czech, both options are there.
Any ideas how to fix/add it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this [app](https://github.com/varzan/extra-keyboard-layouts) (Extra Keyboard Layouts) which is adding "Hungarian 101 QWERTY" layout. If you need more modifications you can edit or add more layouts inside "main/res/raw" folder and build your own version of this application.